# Is there an embedded board that runs a GUI?

Tags: gui

I'm working on a project that currently uses an embedded board with the Debian OS.  However, we are looking for a new board, and I was wondering if anyone knows of a board that comes loaded with a GUI such as Ubuntu?  I'm looking for a board that I can plug in a monitor and keyboard and just develop on the board using a GUI much like a complete laptop.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raspberry Pi! You can install the [Debian-based Raspbian](https://www.raspbian.org/) or if you're going to use a Raspberry Pi 2 or Pi 3, you can install [Ubuntu MATE for the Raspberry Pi 2 and Raspberry Pi 3](https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/).

Both of those come with a GUI built-in and have very good support. They're also fairly low power, so a great option for an embedded system.

Another option would be the BeagleBone Black. While they aren't officially supported by BeagleBone, you can [install Ubuntu-desktop and GNOME-desktop](http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:Desktops_On_Ubuntu/Debian).

Answer (score 0):

Qualcomm Snapdragon based development boards are available with ubuntu/debian OS supports. More [info](https://eragon.einfochips.com/).